# requestLocationUpdates in android taking lot of time to show first update

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get location updates in android using requestLocationUpdates

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

But for me it is taking too long time to show the GPS coordinates, instead of GPS icon, it is showing some different icon "which is trying to connect to some network", i am really not getting what is the problem?

Comment: what is "a lot" of time? How many seconds?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good view to open sky then you should get a location withing 20-30s, or even fatser.

If you are unlucky to have one of the (view?) strange designed android phones that need an internet connection even for initializing the GPS-chip, then you are in an unlucky situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the GPS provider.

```
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
```

Instead, use the network provider as that is much faster.

```
    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.
```

So, your code should read :

```
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener)
```

This should be able to speed up your location response.

Comment: It can speed it up but it will not be as accuarate as GPS